# SQL Server Query to ignore duplicate by id,date and hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

First of all thank you for looking.
just little information: i cannot alter the table as the software does not like it, i can create new table.

What I'm trying to achieve is employee clocking time stamp but SQL server saves duplicate and also returns duplicates.

I need to group the time stamp by hour and/or hours each user.

I've tried different quires and even searched every where sorry I'm new to this so might missed something.

Table:
USERID,checktime
current SQL query:

```
SELECT  top 5
   USERID,checktime,
   (convert(varchar, checktime, 101) ) AS checktime,
   DATEPART(hh,checktime) AS OnHour
   FROM CHECKINOUT where userid ='223'
   GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(HOUR, checktime),
   USERID,checktime 
   order by USERID
```

Result:

```
USERID  checktime   checktime   OnHour
223 2015-06-14 07:40:09.000 06/14/2015  7 
223 2015-06-14 07:40:18.000 06/14/2015  7 --- Duplicate
223 2015-06-14 07:40:36.000 06/14/2015  7 --- Duplicate
223 2015-06-15 16:23:32.000 06/15/2015  16
223 2015-06-16 16:19:31.000 06/16/2015  16 ---Duplicate
```

[Please check image for ref:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vN3Y.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want single records per hour, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT top 5 USERID, MIN(checktime) as checktime,
       cast(checktime as date) as checkdate,
       datepart(hour, checktime) as checkhour
FROM CHECKINOUT 
WHERE userid = '223'
GROUP BY userid, cast(checktime as date), datepart(hour, checktime)
ORDER BY USERID;
```

Notes:

- SQL Server has a wealth of functions for extracting date parts.  You don't have to use obscure formatting options on `convert()`.
- When using `datepart()`, it is a good habit to spell out the date part name.  Although abbreviations are understood, "hour" is quite unambiguous and indicates exactly your intent.
- To remove the time component, use `cast(... as date)`.
- Never use `varchar()` in SQL Server without a length.  The default length varies by context.  To prevent unintended areas, just be explicit.

Comment: Thanks but it still has duplicate records

Comment: @user2088945 . . . This should at most one record for the user in each date/hour combination.  What is your definition of duplicate?

Comment: Each user should not have more then 2 records for each day, one person cannot clock in say at 07:30 and again 07:40, my issue the software saves duplicate but i need SQL to ignore the duplicates.

eg. right now it will out put both
James 07:30 
James 07:40

But it should be only
James 07:30 - only

Comment: SOMETHING LIKE THIS: `SELECT top 5 ino.USERID,ufo.NAME, CONVERT(varchar(13), ino.CHECKTIME , 120) as dateH
FROM CHECKINOUT ino
INNER JOIN USERINFO ufo ON ino.USERID = ufo.USERID
AND ufo.BADGENUMBER ='23'
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(13), ino.CHECKTIME , 120),ino.USERID,ufo.NAME
ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(13), ino.CHECKTIME , 120)` WORKS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT A.*,
        CASE WHEN A.RN>1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Duplicate
FROM (SELECT *
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(HOUR, checktime) ORDER BY checktime) AS 'RN'
      FROM CHECKINOUT WHERE userid = '223') AS A`

`// RN > 1 --> duplicates`

Answer (score 0):

- In the SELECT statement you have 2 colums with the same name 'checktime'.
- Try to use AGGREGATE in your select statement, MIN or MAX for example.
- Refering in the GROUP BY clause must be the same as in the SELECT statement. You have:
  SELECT statement: DATEPART(hh,checktime)
  GROUP BY clause: DATEPART(HOUR,checktime)